# Yii2 disabled textInput ActiveForm

Tags: yii2

how to disabled textInput in ActiveForm ?
i try like this but can't

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'title_series')->textInput(['class' => 'form-control class-content-title_series', 'placeholder' => 'Title', 'disabled' => 'disabled'])->label(false) ?>
```

'disabled' => 'disabled or 'disabled' => true
both of them can't too

Comment: you can try `['readonly' => true]`

Comment: thanks for reply. readonly and disabled is different, i need disabled input element not readonly

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I don't really know yii2/ActiveForm, but I believe you need to do it this way:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'title_series')->textInput(['class' => 'form-control class-content-title_series', 'placeholder' => 'Title', 'disabled' => true])->label(false) ?>
```

Comment: @CaspianKing Are you absolutely sure it is not disabled? I did some searching and that is what I was able to find. Are you using inspect element in your browser to check if the disabled attribute has been added to the input in the html?

Comment: I've checked element and the results is like this
<div class="form-group field-content-title_series">

<input type="text" id="content-title_series" class="form-control class-content-title_series" name="Content[title_series]" placeholder="Title">

<div class="help-block"></div>
</div>

Comment: This is correct. Just tested it and it works. Make sure changes to file are really applied (maybe old version was loaded?).

Comment: i'm sorry, my fault
there jquery for false disabled input
the answer from keith is correct

Comment: @CaspianKing ah good! :) If my answer is correct, please mark is as correct ;)

Answer (score 2):

To ensure that the field values are send on submit, use

```
echo $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput([
    'readonly' => true,
]);
```

This solution won in 50 different tries.

Answer (score 0):

I think issue was with your `label` thing

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'title_series')->textInput(['class' => 'form-control class-content-title_series', 'placeholder' => 'Title', 'disabled' => 'true'])->label(''); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working, keep the disabled in same array than 'value'

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'type')->textInput(['value' => $type,'disabled' => true]) ?>
```